# dylib remote debugging on an iOS device with lldb

Tags: ios, shared-libraries, xcode5, remote-debugging, lldb

I am developing a shared library for an iOS app (that will be distributed in-house, so using dylibs is not an issue). Dylib and the app are two different targets in the same XCode project, so that in the simulator I can correctly debug the dylib. When I run the app on the device I can correctly remote debug the app but I can't debug the code of the shared library. Since I don't know what to expect I can't understand if I set something wrong in the Build settings or this is a limitation of lldb when remote debugging. Is there something I should check or do?

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault: it is definitely possible to remote debug dylibs even on external devices.